# How to find the value of the parameter a in this transfer function?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, complex-systems

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find the value of the parameter $a$ in this transfer function?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/21654/how-to-find-the-value-of-the-parameter-a-in-this-transfer-function)

I am given a transfer function of a second-order system as:
$$G(s)=\frac{a}{s^{2}+4s+a}$$
and I need to find the value of the parameter a that will make the damping coefficient $$\zeta=.7$$ I am not sure how to do this but I might have found something that might have helped so I am going to take a stab at it. I found a transfer function in the book of a second order spring-mass-damper system with an external applied force in the book as:
$$G(s)=\frac{a}{m\omega_{n}^{2}}(\frac{\omega_{n}^{2}}{s^{2}+2\omega_{n}\zeta+\omega_{n}^{2}})$$

I was thinking that I could writeZx:
$$2\omega_{n}^{2}\zeta=4$$ and $$\omega_{n}^{2}=a$$
asd
And then solve for a. Would this be possible?

Comment: This is off topic for this forum without a direct electronics application.

Comment: Canonical 2nd order tf form is close to the factor within the brackets of G(s), so you can do what you propose with two small changes: \$2\omega\zeta s=4\$ (not \$2\omega^2\zeta=4\$).

Comment: http://www-users.aston.ac.uk/~norriswt/ControlNotes/2nd%20order%20transfer%20function.pdf

Comment: Err, I made a small error. Oh well. No one will ever see it. ;)

Comment: @tyblu busted! The 's' is not in the coefficient :)

Comment: The situation where this question was migrated from electronics and created a duplicate is *why* [cross-posting is discouraged](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/896/520). In the future, please try one site at a time.

Answer (score 0):

A general second order equation is given as

```
                 G(s)= ω^2/(s^2+ 2ζω+ω^2 )
```

Hence, ω = √a,

```
   2ζω = 4
```

Solving yeild a=8.163 rad/sec

So, I guess you were headed in the right direction. :)